# XmlBeans vs Digester which is good at handling huge xml files?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am creating a webservice which is going to parse huge xml files from different requests. I was exploring different xml parsers from which I read about [XmlBeans](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxmlbeans.apache.org%2F&ei=SJFFTNTVH5PKcfTDzYwF&usg=AFQjCNGN_wjo_uVxCn3dsrhwkz1WoLHcbA&sig2=XC8yPzfoYSyN9d2JI1RbOQ) and [Digester](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcommons.apache.org%2Fdigester%2F&ei=WZFFTNa_LYXZcenMifQE&usg=AFQjCNH8BYieOqal9j_i3fIWlDwbncVoPA&sig2=-FNvs2SHsaxZRmidKsEK3g) would be easy to use and are very efficient. I felt Digester easier than that of XmlBeans but from documentation of XmlBeans I came to know that it uses Saxon 8.6.1 which is prepared by [CERN](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cern.ch%2F&ei=kJBFTI7HCcaPcf-DmPUE&usg=AFQjCNH2ifeWAgK7w0t_SlAiQzvAZu4kAQ&sig2=1reDkAWZ-F2ZnH9RHXEqmw) so it must be better than that of  Digester.

So which one should I go with XmlBeans or Digester for this scenario ?

Comment: XmlBeans is almost certainly not good for large documents, it loads the whole thing into memory at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you have really huge XML files, than I don't recommend either of them. For high performance XML processing there are other solutions, or even custom parsers that are at least an order of magnitude better than those you describe. What to choose for huge XML files also depends partially on what you have: more memory or more CPU.

E.g. http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/ might be one fast alternative, but there are many others, so if your application's performance is critical, than you really need to compare them with some tests under your own realistic conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this link. This project is indeed very very fast :).